# Triggering profiles associated with an item in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I have a question about triggering profiles associated with an item. If a visitor visits a page, the profiles associated with that page are triggered for that visitor.

How can I trigger the profiles associated with an item in code? The item is not a page. I only want to trigger the profiles if a visitor matches some kind of conidtion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is all done through the `startTracking` pipeline. Unfortunately, it looks as if Sitecore has "hard coded" the pipeline to use the Context Item. You should be able to accomplish this though by replacing the `ProcessItem` processor.

Note: The following is untested.

1. Create a subclass of `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.StartTrackingArgs` which has an `Item` property
2. Create a subclass of `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.ProcessItem`. Use reflector or ILSpy to pull the existing logic of the `Process` method. If the `StartTrackingArgs` passed in are of your subclass, and an `Item` property is specified, use it instead of the context item.
3. Replace the type of the existing `ProcessItem` in the `startTracking` pipeline using an [Include config with a patch:attribute](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx).
4. To trigger the call, construct an instance of your `StartTrackingArgs` and call `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.StartTrackingPipeline.Run(yourArgs)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought that this would be much easier to accomplish. I don't have much experience with Sitecore, so if I have enough time I will look into this and let you know if it works.

Comment: Good luck. If you are new to Sitecore pipelines, you may find this article helpful: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Pipelines-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx